# Limit of a sequence defined by a recurrence relation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to find the limit of the sequence defined as follows:

- $u_0>0$
- $u_{n+1} = \sqrt{u_n+\sqrt{u_{n-1} + \ldots + \sqrt{u_0}}}$

I really have no idea for that one... Not even how to start. Should I try to consider a series or something? Using the fact that every term of this sequence is positive?

Comment: Hint: Simplify the recurrence relation so that $u_{n+1}$ only depends on $u_n$.

Comment: Oh my, I didn't even see that simplification... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your series so that it only replies on the previous result, and not all results up to that point, $u_n = f(u_{n-1})\\\\$.

Once you have things in this form, you look for fixed points by setting $u_n$ and $u_{n-1}$ to the same value, essentially solving $x = f(x)$.  These $x$ values, the fixed points of your recurrence relation, tell you which values your series will always tend towards in the long run.

If you need a further hint, for your particular relation I got fixed values of 0 and 2. Since $u_0 >0$, all solutions should tend towards 2.

Comment: So basically the recurrence relation can be written as un+1=√(2un), meaning I study the function x --> √(2x). And well, with x=√(2x) I find x=2...

I remember know that we sometimes use the fixed points hen studying sequences, may I just ask why the fixed point is the limit of a sequence? I can't recall.

 
(thanks for the help of course :D)

Comment: This link will probably explain it better than I can:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Stability_of_nonlinear_first-order_recurrences

Comment: One last question, am I not supposed to first prove the convergence of the sequence before using the fixed points?

Comment: They are not related, in the sense that their logics are independant. There are sequences that, given that the limit exists, it can be computed, but nonetheless it can be shown to diverge. These are the two steps of the proof, but the order is up to you.